# ATG Site Manager reserved words

Tags: java, oracle, atg

I have a problem with ATG Site Builder, when I set the new URL in BCC Site Manager like '/action/smth' I got 404 error message on that page. I think it's reserved word. I have been reading ATG documentation but I did not found any information about that. Maybe someone had the same troubles, because I don't know why every times I got 404 error on page.
[example screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPyEd.png)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Bonatti Within the scope of ATG (an in particular the BCC) the above is a completely valid question - though it could be worded slighly better. Not sure why you would flag it as otherwise.

Comment: Like the automated text, I am asking the questioning person to add details on what problem he is facing.... as far as I read this, I can only see this question: `Where is the manual with the reserved words on tool X`. Since I couldnt understand how this is programming related, then I flagged the question.

Comment: Don't guess. Web sites and URLs don't have reserved words. Stick to the actual problem, which appears to be 100% off-topic here.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that defining and understanding the `web.xml` as well as the idea of a `context-root` is actually not off-topic. Hopefully I've answered the actual question within the context of `ATG` and `Java` in which it was asked.

Answer (score 0):

The 'reserved words' that you refer to don't really exist. What you actually mean is the various `context-roots` of the ATG Application that are available. In an 'out-of-the-box' scenario the following context roots are defined:

```
/dyn
/dyn/admin
/rest
/atg
/AssetBrowse
/PubPortlets
```

All of these are defined in your web.xml as well as the web.xml from each of the ATG modules that you include.

What you are looking for though is a very specific `context-root` definition for the `Spindrift Site Builder` application (not a native ATG application but something developed and supported by a 3rd party). As I don't have this readily at hand I can't confirm the `context-root` values that the `Site Builder` module require but you should be able to determine that yourself by inspecting the published `context-roots` in your application server.